# Get a hash’s key name

Tags: hash

This is possibly more of a Twig thing, but if I have a hash…

```
{% set hash = {
    "key": "value"
} %}
```

How can I output the **key name**?

```
{% for value in hash %}
    <span class="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an example of this in the Twig documentation: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys-and-values

In your example, it would be:

```
{% for key, value in hash %}
    <span class="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Brad :thumbsup: